# excel: how to place rows at the bottom of list in sort and filter options?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, cells

Here is what I have at the moment:

1. Click on home ribbon button
2. click sort & filter drop down box

I have a sort option as follows:[image]

As you can see the rows have been commanded to go to the top of my list when one column is green. Though by clicking the last drop down, you can select 'On Bottom' and this will make the cells go to the bottom

I want to do a similar function with a cell value instead of a cell colour. For example when a cell contains the character 'y' it will go to the bottom.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you sort on values then choose the order "A to Z" all the entries with "Y" will go to the bottom.

This of course assumes you have no options that are lower in the alphabet than the letter Y.

**Step 1**

The unsorted list.

[image: original, unsorted list]

**Step 2**

On the custom sort dialog, choose `Values` from the **Sort On** dropdown. Then choose `A to Z` on the **Order** dropdown. Hit **OK**.

[image: Custom sort dialog box]

**Step 3**

The list will then be sorted alphabetically with the Y's appearing at the bottom. This may take some time depending on the size of the list.

[image: Sorted list]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Burgi, though I have a lot of empty cells, and I want the rows to go to the bottom even if empty cells occupy it

Comment: Would it be possible to create a new data type to prevent blanks? Something like "added"